# Send value of text box to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox and need to send the value of the text box when you type some number and the radio button is checked, to a jquery function. The code I'm using now is:

```
var radiobuttoncustom = 0;
if (document.getElementById('radiobuttoncustom').checked) {
    radiobuttoncustom = document.getElementsByName("some_number").value;
}
```

I will then display the results using "radiobuttoncustom" but when the results is displayed it is NaN instead of the number. Right now I'm using the textboxes name to get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection), not an element, which would not have a `value` attribute.

Have you tried:

```
radiobuttoncustom = document.getElementsByName("some_number")[0].value;
```

edit: if you are dealing with numbers, you should also parse them as such:

```
radiobuttoncustom = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("some_number")[0].value, 10);
```

Comment: What query would I use if I didn't use getElementsByName? The code you gave me works, but when I try to add it to another number, it just puts the two together instead of adding them: var ne2 = radiobuttoncustom + 10;
    $('.showtotal').html(ne2);

Comment: @user1612679 you're welcome. if the answer helped you, you should accept it (click the green check mark next to it) so that future visitors can quickly find the best solution.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that I had to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery, why not

```
$('input[name=some_number]').val();
```

and

```
if($('#radiobuttoncustom').prop("checked"))
```